# Swift, random word from let by pressing Button

Tags: swift

I am new here and hope that I do everything right.
Im work on my first iOS app right now and have some questions.
first thank you for your time and your help.

My question:
i wann to make a Button, when I Press the Button I want a output on my screen.

like this:

```
let name = " Dennis, Janine, Robert, Marie"
```

when I press the button I want a Random name from my let name.

but I have no idea how I make it random and how I can show it on my Screen

Hope you can help me Thank you !!!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994747-randomelement

Comment: Can you show what have you tried? Two hints: use a String Array for the names and search for Random

Comment: let names = "Dennis, Janine, Robert, Marie".components(separatedBy: ",")
let randomName = names.randomElement()!
print("randomName :- \(randomName)")

Comment: okay thx I try this later :D